# How to write C program for 8259 controller

Tags: c

I am working on interrupts. I have to understand how to use 8259 PIC. Can anyone guide me how to write a program in C for it. (I already worked on 8051) I suppose it can be used as 8051.

Comment: this may help you http://retired.beyondlogic.org/interrupts/interupt.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a set of definitions common to the rest of this section. For the outb(), inb() and io_wait() functions, [see this page.](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples#I.2FO_access)

```
#define PIC1        0x20        /* IO base address for master PIC */
#define PIC2        0xA0        /* IO base address for slave PIC */
#define PIC1_COMMAND    PIC1
#define PIC1_DATA   (PIC1+1)
#define PIC2_COMMAND    PIC2
#define PIC2_DATA   (PIC2+1)
```

Perhaps the most common command issued to the PIC chips is the end of interrupt (EOI) command (code 0x20). This is issued to the PIC chips at the end of an IRQ-based interrupt routine. If the IRQ came from the Master PIC, it is sufficient to issue this command only to the Master PIC; however if the IRQ came from the Slave PIC, it is necessary to issue the command to both PIC chips.

```
#define PIC_EOI     0x20        /* End-of-interrupt command code */

void PIC_sendEOI(unsigned char irq)
{
    if(irq >= 8)
        outb(PIC2_COMMAND,PIC_EOI);

    outb(PIC1_COMMAND,PIC_EOI);
}
```

When you enter protected mode (or even before hand, if you're not using GRUB) the first command you will need to give the two PICs is the initialise command (code 0x11). This command makes the PIC wait for 3 extra "initialisation words" on the data port. These bytes give the PIC:

1. Its vector offset. (ICW2)
2. Tell it how it is wired to master/slaves. (ICW3)
3. Gives additional information about the environment. (ICW4)

> ```
> #define ICW1_ICW4 0x01        /* ICW4 (not) needed */
> #define ICW1_SINGLE   0x02        /* Single (cascade) mode */
> #define ICW1_INTERVAL4    0x04        /* Call address interval 4 (8) */
> #define ICW1_LEVEL    0x08        /* Level triggered (edge) mode */
> #define ICW1_INIT 0x10        /* Initialization - required! */
>
> #define ICW4_8086 0x01        /* 8086/88 (MCS-80/85) mode */
> #define ICW4_AUTO 0x02        /* Auto (normal) EOI */
> #define ICW4_BUF_SLAVE    0x08        /* Buffered mode/slave */
> #define ICW4_BUF_MASTER   0x0C        /* Buffered mode/master */
> #define ICW4_SFNM 0x10        /* Special fully nested (not) */
> ```

```
void PIC_remap(int offset1, int offset2)
{
    unsigned char a1, a2;

    a1 = inb(PIC1_DATA);                        // save masks
    a2 = inb(PIC2_DATA);

    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT+ICW1_ICW4);  // starts the initialization sequence (in cascade mode)
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT+ICW1_ICW4);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC1_DATA, offset1);                 // ICW2: Master PIC vector offset
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, offset2);                 // ICW2: Slave PIC vector offset
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC1_DATA, 4);                       // ICW3: tell Master PIC that there is a slave PIC at IRQ2 (0000 0100)
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, 2);                       // ICW3: tell Slave PIC its cascade identity (0000 0010)
    io_wait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, a1);   // restore saved masks.
    outb(PIC2_DATA, a2);
}
```

For masking

```
void IRQ_set_mask(unsigned char IRQline) {
    uint16_t port;
    uint8_t value;

    if(IRQline < 8) {
        port = PIC1_DATA;
    } else {
        port = PIC2_DATA;
        IRQline -= 8;
    }
    value = inb(port) | (1 << IRQline);
    outb(port, value);        
}

void IRQ_clear_mask(unsigned char IRQline) {
    uint16_t port;
    uint8_t value;

    if(IRQline < 8) {
        port = PIC1_DATA;
    } else {
        port = PIC2_DATA;
        IRQline -= 8;
    }
    value = inb(port) & ~(1 << IRQline);
    outb(port, value);        
}
```